# Urn with balls, Bayes

Tags: probability

The urn consists 4 balls (black and white) with at least 1 white. Two randomly drawed balls were both white. What it the probability of getting white ball again?

My solution:

```
balls(w/b)    || 4:0  | 3:1  | 2:2  | 1:3  | 0:4
P(prior)      || 1/15 | 4/15 | 6/15 | 4/15 | 0/15
P(2w|prior)   || 1    | 1/2  | 1/6  | 0    | 0
P(posterior)  || 1/4  | 1/2  | 1/4  | 0    | 0
P(w|posterior)|| 1    | 1/2  | 0    | 0    | 0

P(w) = ∫P(w|u) P(u) du = 1 * 1/4 + 1/2 * 1/2 + 0 * 1/4 = 1/2
```

But the answer is $7/12$. Where have I made a mistake?

The prior was assumed:

```
balls(w/b)    || 4:0 | 3:1 | 2:2 | 1:3 | 0:4
P(prior)      || 1/8 | 3/8 | 3/8 | 1/8 | 0/8
```

Meaning the first ball was white and all others were decided by coin toss. However, I think the original formulation does not correspond to this problem and should be replaced with something like:

```
In an urn with a white ball one puts another 3 balls ...
```

Comment: This is really too vague.  What probability distribution covers the original choice of colors?  Are each of the four possibilities $\{1W,2W,3W,4W\}$ equally likely?  Was the color of each ball decided by a coin toss?  And the drawing...is that done with replacement?  Without replacement?

Comment: I used assumption that color decided by coin toss, where we reject all black balls case. With replacement the answer is $3/4$, which requires only modification of P(w|posterior). Anyway, how can I obtain $7/12$?

Comment: Try uniform prior ($\frac 14$ for each of the four cases)?  If no assumptions were given, it's hard to try to think through every possibility.

Comment: For uniform prior I obtained  $3/4$ without, and $7/8$ with replacement. Anyway, this is not $7/12$ :)

Comment: Like I say...if the problem is silent on these questions, it seems hard to try to guess what they had in mind.  Is there any way you could get that clarified?  Have you printed the problem exactly as it appears?

Comment: Actually, the question is not "how to solve this problem", but "which formulation of this problem lead to $7/12$" :)

Comment: Can you reprint the problem exactly as it appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $4$ different plausible assumptions how this problem could have been intended: with or without replacement, and with a uniform prior for the colour counts or the ball colours.

Without replacement with uniform colour counts we have

$$
\def\p#1{\textsf{Pr}\left(#1\right)}\p{W_3\mid W_1\cap W_2}=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^4\p{W_3\cap W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}{\sum_{k=2}^4\p{W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}=\frac{0+\frac14+1}{\frac16+\frac12+1}=\frac34\;.
$$

With replacement with uniform colour counts we have

$$
\p{W_3\mid W_1\cap W_2}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^4\p{W_3\cap W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}{\sum_{k=1}^4\p{W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^4\left(\frac k4\right)^3}{\sum_{k=1}^4\left(\frac k4\right)^2}=\frac56\;.
$$

Without replacement with uniform ball colours we have

$$
\p{W_3\mid W_1\cap W_2}=\frac{\sum_{k=2}^4\p{W_3\cap W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}{\sum_{k=2}^4\p{W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}=\frac{6\cdot0+4\cdot\frac14+1\cdot1}{6\cdot\frac16+4\cdot\frac12+1\cdot1}=\frac12\;.
$$

With replacement with uniform ball colours we have

$$
\p{W_3\mid W_1\cap W_2}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^4\p{W_3\cap W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}{\sum_{k=1}^4\p{W_1\cap W_2\cap\text{$k$ white}}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^4\binom4k\left(\frac k4\right)^3}{\sum_{k=1}^4\binom4k\left(\frac k4\right)^2}=\frac7{10}\;.
$$

Thus none of the obvious possibilities lead to the answer $\frac7{12}$.

Note that the information "with at least $1$ white" is irrelevant, since we know from drawing white balls that there's at least $1$ white ball.

Note also that the probability $\frac12$ in the case without replacement with uniform ball colours reflects the fact that in this case the previously drawn balls don't give us any information about the remaining balls.